# What syntax is this? "{{post.price}}"

Tags: php, theme-development, custom-field, templates

I am working on a WordPress theme that someone else worked on and I am trying to add a custom field to display certain text on the homepage. Right now it does not display anything if I add the custom field, even though the same field works on single pages.

To display certain custom fields, they put them in the same format as `{{post.price}}` How can I change the format of my custom field to this format they use? I am hoping by identifying the syntax it will help me figure out how to get my custom field into the same format so it will display on homepage.

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer the question, e.g. the file extension of the file it appears in, as well as its surrounding context. It's almost certainly a templating system but Mustache? Twig? Handlebars? JSX? It's impossible to tell without context

Comment: It appears in a .php file. Not sure if the tag is related to a specific plugin. i dont need any plugins that stand out.

Comment: Is it inside a `<script></script>` tag? Looks like a JS template.

Comment: have you tried just outputting the custom fields normally?

Comment: It is not in a script tag.

Comment: When I try outputting a custom field normally, it doesn't display anything. It used to, but then I had a developer add ajax infinite scroll to the website. In the process, all my previous custom fields were changed tot he new format I cited above. Now when i try to add a new field nothing happens, which is why I want to figure out how to convert it to that syntax.

Comment: @user91325 The syntax you posted above is the Angular syntax. Check if the person changed your code, has fetched the data using any javascript/jQuery call & RestAPI.